# Segregating the windows on different workspaces in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: windows, ubuntu-11.10, workspace

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 11.10. Though overall satisfied with the interface, one thing which irked me in the Unity environment is that if I open an application (a web browser, for example) in one of the workspaces, it is also visible (on the Unity toolbar, minimized) on the other workspaces. This was not so in 10.10. Is there some easy way to fix this, other than, of course, disabling Unity entirely, so that I may be able to regard the four workspaces as four different desktops entirely?

Answer (score 0):

In workspace switcher drag the window to the top and hold until a tinted box covers all four workspaces, then release. You will now not be able to cover multiple workspaces with a window. Unsure how to disable.

This is from my experience, and I *just* got Ubuntu.